# get text by class in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want get `test` inside this example. Why it doesn't work?

HTML

```
<div id="partTypes">
    <div class="partType">
        <div class="details"> <span class="name">test</span>

        </div>
        <div class="buttons">
            <input class="addCart" type="button" value="click me" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.addCart').live('click', function () {
        var $partType = $(this).closest('div.partType');
        alert($partType.filter('span.name').text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Also, `.live()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, so try to use `.on()` instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
alert($partType.filter('span.name').text());
```

to:

```
alert($partType.find('span.name').text());
```

Ideally you also want to stop using `.live()` and move to `.on()` (since live was deprecated awhile ago and removed in 1.9) so the whole block would be:

```
$('input.addCart').on('click', function () {
    var $partType = $(this).closest('div.partType');
    alert($partType.find('span.name').text());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/y9QWZ/)**

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.addCart').click(function () {
        var $partType = $(this).closest('div.partType');
        alert($partType.find('span.name').text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`.filter()` will apply the filter to the passed set of elements, where as you want to look at the descendent elements for which you need to use `find()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.addCart').live('click', function () {
        var $partType = $(this).closest('div.partType');
        alert($partType.find('span.name').text());
    });
});
```

[.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/): Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/): Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.